# Pass windows identity to web api layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I know this question has been fleshed out in the past, but I'm wondering if folks can comment from a more update to date perspective.

I have an MVC web app that authenticates using windows authentication and passes requests to a web.api service layer.

I'm looking to perform role-based authorization using AuthorizeAttribute at the service layer controller layer.

I'm also hoping to do this using the async method from HttpClient.

I've tried invoking the HttpClient as new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true, UseDefaultCredentials = true }); in my web app client wrapper but this doesn't seem to do the job.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would question your design decisions.  Why are you calling a separate web api layer from your MVC web app?

Comment: These are the business requirements I have. :(

Comment: You would probably have to get your MVC site to impersonate the user that was logged in so that the call to the service layer was in effect from that user. Do a search for impersonation.

Comment: Thanks. Will do!